# Angular redirect after login is behavior very strange

Tags: angular, router

I have a angular component called Login, after login success, the page should refresh and navigation bar should refresh aswell, then I wish the page can be redirect to another component page - welcome, here is the code:

```js
    import { TokenStorageService } from './../_services/token-storage.service';
    import { AuthService } from './../_services/auth.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
      form: any = {};
      isLoggedIn = false;
      isLoginFailed = false;
      errorMessage = '';
      roles: string[] = [];
    
      constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService,
        private router: Router
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
      reloadPage(): void {
        window.location.reload();
      }
      onSubmit(): void {
        this.authService.userLogin(this.form).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accesstoken);
            this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);
            this.isLoginFailed = false;
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
            if ((this.isLoggedIn = true)) {
              this.reloadPage();
              this.router.navigate(['../welcome']);
            }
          },
          (err) => {
            this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
            this.isLoginFailed = true;
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Now the behaviour looks very strange...
I can see I successfully login  and page jump to welcome page in 2 seconds and suddenly back to login page, and it looks like I have not loggin,but the nav bar has been refresh and it tells me the user information since they have been stored in the Storage Service.

Here is the HTML of login page:

```html
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card card-container">
        <img
          id="BusyQA-icon"
          src="../../assets/img/busyqa-icon.jpg"
          class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block"
        />
        <form
          action=""
          *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"
          name="form"
          (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"
          #f="ngForm"
          novalidate
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="username"
              [(ngModel)]="form.username"
              required
              placeholder="please insert your username"
              #username="ngModel"
            />
            <div
              class="alert alert-danger"
              role="alert"
              *ngIf="f.submitted && username.invalid"
            >
              Username is required!
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Please insert your password"
              [(ngModel)]="form.password"
              required
              minlength="6"
              #password="ngModel"
            />
            <div
              class="alert alert-danger"
              role="alert"
              *ngIf="f.submitted && password.invalid"
            >
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
                Password must be at least 6 characters
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
            &nbsp;
    
            <a routerLink="/home"
              ><button
                ng-href=""
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg"
              >
                Cancel
              </button></a
            >
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <div
              class="alert alert-danger"
              role="alert"
              *ngIf="f.submitted && isLoginFailed"
            >
              Login failed: {{ errorMessage }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
          Logged in as {{ roles }}.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone give me some advise?

Thanks!

Comment: `if ((this.isLoggedIn = true)) {` you are missing an equal sign there (or two), should be `if ((this.isLoggedIn == true)) {` or even better `if (this.isLoggedIn) {`

Comment: Can you share the part of the app where you try to check for a saved token as `location.reload()` will reload the whole page (app)

Comment: A@AviadP. , it still direct to page 1 second and jumping back to login page....
The way I solve it is : if (this.isLoggedIn == true) {
          this.router.navigate(['../welcome']).then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        }
But what the different with this??? :
 if (this.isLoggedIn == true) {
          this.router.navigate(['../welcome'])
          this.reloadPage()
        }
that Then() solution working good now.

Comment: @AviadP. Sorry for the format and english, I just want to know the difference with those two approach and why the one use Then() working as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reloading the page?
I believe that all you have to do is to delete `this.reloadPage();`
Change this:

```
    if ((this.isLoggedIn = true)) {
          this.reloadPage();
          this.router.navigate(['../welcome']);
        }
```

to this:

```
    if ((this.isLoggedIn = true)) {
          this.router.navigate(['../welcome']);
        }
```